# In a CSRF Protection in token-based authentication in mern stack, How to retrieve value from HttpOnly cookie?

Tags: csrf, mern, setcookie, csrf-token

I am implementing a csrf protection in token based authentication in mern stack using Double Submit Cookie approach.

Here, I am generating access token named as token, refresh token, and csrf token. Send these tokens in HttpOnly cookie. And also encrypted refresh token will be stored in database.

```js
module.exports.signup_user = async (req, res) => {
    try {

        /*
          * req.body validation code is here
          *
        */

        const user = new User({
            username,
            fullName,
            email,
            password: hashPassword,
        });

        const token = generateJWTToken({ userId: user._id, role: 'user' });
        const refreshToken = generateRefreshToken({ userId: user._id, role: 'user' });
        const csrfToken = generateCSRFToken();
        const encryptedRF = encryptRefreshToken(refreshToken);

        res.cookie('_accessToken', token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false,
            sameSite: 'lax',
            maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000
        });
        res.cookie('_csrf', csrfToken, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false,
            sameSite: 'lax',
        });
        res.cookie('_refreshToken', encryptedRF, {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false,
            sameSite: 'lax',
            maxAge: 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        });

        user.refreshToken = encryptedRF;

        await user.save();

        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: 'User registered successfully',
        })

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            error: "Internal server error"
        });
    }
}
```

The given below is code for checking csrf token in client request:
Here, I am retrieving csrf token values from cookies in request and request headers named as 'x-csrf-token'.

```js
module.exports.csrfProtection = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (['GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'].includes(req.method)) {
           return next();
        }
 
        const cookieCsrfToken = req.cookies._csrf;
        const requestCsrfToken = req.get('x-csrf-token'); 

        if (!requestCsrfToken || !cookieCsrfToken) {
            res.status(401)
                .json({
                    success: false,
                    error: 'Unauthorized'
                });
            return;
        }
        if (requestCsrfToken !== cookieCsrfToken) {
            res.status(401)
                .json({
                    success: false,
                    error: 'Invalid token.'
                });
            return;
        }
        next();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.status(500).json({ 
            success: false, 
            error: "Internal server error" 
        });
        return;
    }
}
```

But, How to get csrf token value in client side? Because HttpOnly cookies cannot be accessed directly from JavaScript in the browser due to security restrictions.
Do I need to also send csrf token from server to client in request body?
Am I doing wrong to implement this csrf protection in token based authentication?

Thanks

Comment: The server must communicate the CSRF token to the client in such a way that the client can read it and use it in a subsequent request. So if the CSRF token is communicated via a cookie, that cookie cannot be HttpOnly, because the client must be able to read it.

Comment: Thank you, But is it a recommended way? Because If I set the CSRF token as a non-HttpOnly cookie, it becomes vulnerable to being read or tampered with by JavaScript code.